# U-shaped magnet and the moving charge: Where is the origin of the Lorentz force from the viewpoint of the moving charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, reference-frames

Assume that a charge $+q$ is located at rest between the poles of an infinitely long U-shaped magnet, which is laid along the $x$-axis. If the charge slowly accelerates to a velocity $v$ along $x$ and perpendicular to the magnetic field, we know that the Lorentz force is exerted on the charge abruptly considering the instantaneous velocity of the charge. [See the Figure.] However, what happens from the viewpoint of the charge?

The charge asserts that the *moving* magnet produces an electric field perpendicular to the magnetic field, which exerts a force on it. However, where is the origin of this electric field in the view of classical electromagnetism? From the viewpoint of the charge, the only origin seems to be the change in the magnetic field of the moving magnet that occurs near the *edges* of the magnet that are located far distant from the charge. Remember that since the magnet is infinitely long, the magnetic field is uniform at any finite distances from the charge along the $x$-axis. Therefore, from the standpoint of the charge, no $\partial B/\partial t$ happens near the charge but at infinite distances away from the charge where the edges of the magnet produce a nonuniform pattern for the magnetic field.

In this case, by the motion of these *edges*, an electrical field of $\partial B/\partial t$ is produced, however, due to the limited speed of light, it takes time for the induced electric field to reach the charge from infinitely large distances. Therefore, the charge claims that there is a non-zero period of time during which the induced electric field has not reached the charge yet, and thus no Lorentz force is being exerted on it. This problem seems to be paradoxical since the observer at rest with respect to the magnet detects an instantaneous Lorentz force exerted on the charge, whereas the observer located on the charge does not detect any orthogonal force to its motion direction when the charge accelerates in that the induced electric field needs a long time to reach it. Where is the problem?

Either consider the acceleration and final velocity $v$ of the charge to be very small so that the charge can be considered inertial or consider the scenario after the charge reaches a constant velocity of $v$.

[image]

Comment: I can think of a few different interpretations of "infinitely long U-shaped magnet".  Can you clarify the geometry?

Comment: Length contraction of the charges that make up the magnetic field in the original frame changes the average  charge density, producing an electric field that exerts a force on the charge

Comment: @BowlOfRed Figure is added.

Comment: @jensenpaull $v$ is assumed to be below relativistic velocities. Moreover, in which direction this electric field is produced due to the change in the average charge density? Is it perpendicular to the magnetic field inside the magnet?

Comment: Relativity happens at the smallest velocities  and is essential for understanding how there is no paradox here.  Roughly speaking the field produced is one that has the same effect on the charge as the magnetic field did in the stationary frame, more or less

Comment: It has nothing to do with edges. It's just that moving magnetic dipoles have electric dipole moments.

Comment: @knzhou I think that if we want to apply Maxwell's equations from the viewpoint of the charge, we have to find $\partial B/ \partial t$ somewhere in space to justify an induced electric field. Even if we consider some induced electric dipoles, we must discuss where they appear, and how long it takes for the induced electric field to reach the charge.

Comment: It is evident that from the viewpoint of the moving charge, the net induced electric field is not instantaneous at any arbitrarily chosen point in space, which seems to be problematic.

Comment: If the observer is near the charge, the Lorentz force due to the fringe field will be delayed as well.

Comment: There's no "induction" going on here. In the frame moving to the right, there are _time-independent_ electric dipole moments sourcing a time-independent electric field. It is just like how, in problems where there's a current carrying wire, in other frames the wire will carry charge which creates an E field. Nothing is "inducing" that charge, it just is there.

Comment: @auxsvr What do you mean by *the observer near the charge*? Are they at rest with respect to the charge or to the magnet?

Comment: @knzhou Assume a small bar magnet is located near our Sun at rest with respect to a terrestrial observer. If the magnet moves relative to the observer, how long does it take for the observer to detect the electric field? According to your claim that *there are time-independent electric dipole moments*, the observer detects the electric field instantaneously, whereas I think that it takes nearly *8 min* for the observer to detect the electric field.

Comment: Well, there are two cases. (1) The magnet has always been moving with constant speed. Then there's no problem with causality. In its frame, everything is "always" there. (2) The magnet is accelerating and you want to work in the noninertial frame of the magnet -- in that case Maxwell's equations pick up about 10 additional acceleration-dependent terms and it's a huge pain keeping track of them. But you can't use the ordinary Maxwell's equations to figure out what happens.

Comment: @knzhou According to my original question, I mean the second case. Even if there are 100 additional acceleration-dependent terms, can we not say that reaching the signals of the electric field takes time and is not instantaneous? For simplicity, consider that the magnet accelerates for a small time, say, 1 s, reaching a nonrelativistic constant velocity afterward. What happens *after* experiencing acceleration when the observer has a constant velocity? Does the observer is allowed to claim that the electric field is now filled the space to infinitely large distances?

Answer (score 4):

When we say that there is an uniform magnetic field, it is also necessary to say: according to a frame $X$. It is not possible to have a pure uniform magnetic field (meaning with no electrical field) for any frame.

For this frame, the complete information is $B_x = B_y = 0$, and $B_z = B$, $E_x = E_y = E_z = 0$. (Here I am neglecting the field from the test charge). That defines the electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$ for this frame.

From the frame $Y$, momentarily co-moving with the charge, the tensor is Lorentz transformed, and $E_y \neq 0$.

The situation didn't change, and it is reflected bt the fact that the tensor is the same. Its components however changed due to the change of frame

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

> where is the origin of this electric field in the view of classical electromagnetism?

This question can be answered by considering the magnetization-polarization tensor, as described in the textbook Classical Electromagnetic Theory, by Jack Vanderlinde (2004, pp. 313–328). The magnetization-polarization tensor is given by: $${\mathcal {M}}^{\mu \nu }={\begin{pmatrix}0 & P_{x}c & P_{y}c & P_{z}c\\-P_{x}c & 0 & -M_{z} & M_{y}\\-P_{y}c & M_{z} & 0 & -M_{x}\\-P_{z}c & -M_{y} & M_{x} & 0\end{pmatrix}}$$

So, in your example in the rest-frame of the magnet (the unprimed frame) it is magnetized in the y direction, so it has a magnetization polarization tensor of $${\mathcal {M}}^{\mu \nu }={\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & M_{y}\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & -M_{y} & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}}$$

Now, ${\mathcal {M}}^{\mu \nu }$ is a standard tensor, so it transforms as usual. In the moving (primed) frame we obtain $${\mathcal {M}}^{\mu' \nu' }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{v \gamma  M_y}{c^2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \gamma  M_y \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{v \gamma  M_y}{c^2} & -\gamma  M_y & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ Thus there is an electric polarization of $\beta \gamma M_y/c^2$ in the $z'$ direction. This polarization is the source of the E field in the $z'$ direction which exerts the force on the charge in its momentarily comoving inertial frame.

> Therefore, from the standpoint of the charge, no ∂B/∂t happens near the charge but at infinite distances away from the charge where the edges of the magnet produce a nonuniform pattern for the magnetic field.

The source of the E field in the primed frame is not from any $\partial \vec B/\partial t$, near or far. It is from the polarization of the same material that is the source of the B field.

> the charge claims that there is a non-zero period of time during which the induced electric field has not reached the charge yet, and thus no Lorentz force is being exerted on it. This problem seems to be paradoxical since the observer at rest with respect to the magnet detects an instantaneous Lorentz force exerted on the charge, whereas the observer located on the charge does not detect any orthogonal force to its motion direction when the charge accelerates in that the induced electric field needs a long time to reach it. Where is the problem?

The charge makes no such claim, and there is no such problem here. The E field from the polarization of the material in the primed frame is present any time the B field from the magnetization is present. There is no such period of time where the force is absent in one frame and present in another frame.